# Unresolved reference webdriver

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver

```
from selenium import webdriver

def f():
 webdriver = webdriver.Chrome()
 return webdriver
```

`PyCharm` выдает ошибку, Unresolved reference webdriver (`import` горит сереньким)
Если же убрать функцию f, то все вполне будет работать нормально.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`x =` внутри функции создаёт локальную переменную `x` (в отсутствии `global x`, `nonlocal x` объявлений). [Из определения языка](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/executionmodel.html#binding-of-names):

> If a name is bound in a block, it is a local variable of that block, unless declared as nonlocal or global.

Поэтому вызов `f()` в вашем случае ведёт к `UnboundLocalError` так как `webdriver` это локальная переменная и вы пытаетесь к ней обратиться до того как ей значение присвоено. Наличие глобальной переменной с тем же именем не имеет значения. В любом месте функции `x` это локальная переменная из-за наличия `x =` внутри. 
См. Python FAQ: [Why am I getting an UnboundLocalError when the variable has a value?](https://docs.python.org/3/faq/programming.html#why-am-i-getting-an-unboundlocalerror-when-the-variable-has-a-value)

Чтобы исправить код, просто переименуйте `webdriver` внутри функции (driver, browser — хорошие кандидаты имён):

```
browser = webdriver.Chrome()
```