# Интерпретатор Python. В какой последовательности исполняется код. Особенности пространства имен и области видимости

Tags: python, namespace, scope

Прошу прощения за нубский вопрос, но прошерстив инет не смог найти полного ответа на интерсующий вопрос. Не могу понять каким образом отрабатывает следующий пример:

```py
x = 10

def func():
    print(x)

func()
```

Здесь код отрабатывает без ошибки. Т.к. перменной **х** нет в локальном пространстве имен, поэтому интерпритатор заглядывает в глобальное пространство, находит ее там и спокойно выводит на экран.

```py
x = 10

def func():
    print(x)
    x = 20

func()
```

В этом же примере я получу ***UnboundLocalError***. Ошибка возникает потому, что интерпритатор знает, что в локальном пространстве имен есть переменная **x**, но значение присваивается после ее вызова.

Я понимаю, что прежде чем выполнить код интерпритатор пробегает по коду и СНАЧАЛА формирует пространство имен. Т.е. перед выполнением данного кода сначала формируется пространство с переменной **x** и функцией **fucn**.

Вопрос!

Когда функция вызывается, перед выполнением функции интерпретатор также сначала пробегает по телу функции и формирует локальное пространство имен? или же он начинает построчно выполнять тело функции?

Также прошу поправить меня, если в своих объяснениях и догадках я допустил какие-то ошибки. Очень хочу досконально разобраться в том, как ведет себя интерпретатор Python и в целом в синтаксисе и особенностях данного языка.

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Unresolved reference webdriver](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/765611/unresolved-reference-webdriver)

Comment: Данный ответ также читал и он частично решил проблему. Но вопрос остается, т.к. меня интересует непосредственно последовательность отработки интерпритатора в данном случае (когда именно он понимает, что x это локальная переменная, и что я не могу вывести ее на экран, т.к. значение ей еще не было передано)

Comment: `когда именно он понимает, что x это локальная переменная` - простой ответ - до начала выполнения. Т.е. интерпретатор строит абстрактное синтаксическое дерево кода, и после этого уже видит, что вы пытаетесь изменить переменную внутри функции. А ошибку кидает уже в момент выполнения, когда видит что вы обращаетесь к неинициализированной локальной переменной.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> Схема разрешения имен в языке Python иногда называется правилом LEGB,
>   название которого состоит из первых букв названий областей видимости:
>
> - Когда внутри функции выполняется обращение к неизвестному имени, интерпретатор пытается отыскать его в четырех областях видимости – в локальной (local, L), затем в локальной области любой объемлющей инструкции def (enclosing, E) или в выражении lambda, затем в глобальной (global,
>     G) и, наконец, во встроенной (built-in, B).

[Изучаем Python, 4-е издание. Марк Лутц (c. 477)](https://codernet.ru/books/python/izuchaem_python_4-e_izdanie_mark_lutc/)

func, прошерстив *local* и *enclosing* namespaces искать будет дальше в *global*, и в первом примере она там и найдет. во втором же, она найдет переменную в  *local*, но поскольку инструкция, вызывающая ее объявлена до инициализации самой переменной, она и вбросит ошибку.

Comment: Благодарю !
Получается я правильно понял, что во втором случае, при попытке обратиться к **х**, интерпретатор начинает шерстить все тело ф-ции с НАЧАЛА в поисках объявления данной переменной ? И в случае если не находит, то идет на верхний namespace и также с самого НАЧАЛА начинает искать объявление данной переменной уже там?

Comment: @TommyHumble именно, но так как он нашел, он дальше не ищет. а вот в 1 примере да - он не нашел, и пошел выше

Answer (score 0):

При вызове функции интерпретатор работает в рамках данной функции и если вы попытаетесь передать в функцию print() значение x до того,как она была объявлена,то вы,естественно,получите ошибку. Если вы не будете объявлять x как локальную переменную в этой функции,то программа считает значение x из глобального пространства имен.